# Op amp is not amplifying a 2 mV signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, small-signal

I trying to amplify an electrical signal created by electrodes on skin, which create a potential of around 2 mV. Therefore, I am using a LM324N operational amplifier (powered by 9 V battery) and creating the same circuit as the following one:

[image: circuit]

This circuit was made for a LM358N op amp but some search on google shows that the LM324N can also be used, but can it?

The problem is that I get this signal on output:

[image: amplified signal]

I tried reading the raw signal with my oscilloscope, and got that ECG crystal clear, but with a potential of 2 mV.

[image: raw signal]

I tried to substitute the 100k ohms resistor with 10k ohms to have a gain of ten as I can read 10 mV with my oscilloscope but I still have this square signal and not the ECG one amplified.

Comment: where did you get the idea that it should work like that?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Well, shouldn't the op amp work like that? I'm very new to amplificator, I found about the formula that says V_s = V_e*(1+100k ohms/1k ohms) so it should amplify the signal to one that has an amplitude of 101*1mV = 101mV

Comment: That circuit is wrong. I don't know why they have the right "lead" labelled where it is. That completely bypasses the rest of the circuitry and makes the op amp behave as an amplifier with infinite gain that cannot actually output infinite voltage so saturates at the power supply voltage whenever it does (i.e. that's what a comparator is). That right "lead" label should be at the same location as the ground.

Comment: If measuring an AC signal, it doesn't make sense to short it out on the terminals.

Comment: The opamp is not powered then it does nothing. Depending on how it is powered then its + input is not biased at the correct DC voltage then it does nothing. It is missing a series input coupling capacitor then its input might be at its negative DC supply voltage so it rectifies the input signal. Of course the second "lead" must be connected to the signal ground and 0V of the power supply, not to the - input. Since the input level is low, shielded audio cable must be used at the input.

Comment: @Audioguru I'm sorry I forgot to mention that the op amp is powered on a 9V battery

Comment: It's a such a shame for Scott W Harden (swharden.com) that draws such circuits. Use Google to find another amplifier circuit, don't waste your time.

Comment: THat's a useless circuit amplifying 30 mVdc from skin voltage with an unbiased unbalanced differential input. DC coupled.  30mV *100 = 3V so the feedback R must be loose and is not biased in the Vcm range. Junk design

Comment: Look for _differential_ or _instrumentation_ amplifier_ solutions. There are many web sites out there showing how to do an EKG instrumentation amplifier with three opamps. Then, look in to a notch filter at your AC line frequency (50Hz or 60Hz).

Comment: @MarkoBuršič  -- just took a peek at Harden's one-op-amp ECG circuit, and a) it isn't the circuit presented here, and b) it's not great, but so long as it doesn't saturate, it should work so long as filtering is done in code, and there's no aliasing.  It would be better with an anti-aliasing filter.  So far as saturation, there's a lot less headroom than I like to use for robust design, but the circuit should work *in many cases*

Comment: All the single opamps shown in this thread are not biased and capacitor-coupled properly. If they are biased and properly coupled then the person having the ECG test would be an antenna that picks up all the 50Hz or 60Hz electrical hum all around him which would be amplified 101 times.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Tom -

I think the author intended a connection on the negative terminal.  This is usually not inferred when two lines cross and it could be better represented like this:

[image]

I couldn't put a picture in the comments, but give it a try.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey John, I made the initial circuit with the connection of the cross and it didn't work either

Comment: I would try removing the capacitor - then maybe put a large resistor to ground from the op amp positive terminal.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't how you go about amplifying a biopotential.

First, since your "answer" can be positive or negative, you need to pay close attention to your supply rails, and you either need a positive and negative supply, or you need to create an offset to amplify around mid-rail.  You've done neither.

Second, you need a differential amplifier.   You *kind of* have a differential amplifier, but not a very good one.  You can build one with op amps, but the far better option is to use an instrumentation amplifier.

Next, biopotential electrodes have many inherent offsets you need to deal with, and the offsets on different electrodes can be different.  In fact, the difference between electrodes (that has nothing to do with ECG) can be big enough to saturate an amplifier with a gain of 100, and that's most likely what you're observing.

A more typical arrangement is a differential amp stage with modest gain, maybe about 5, usually implemented with an instrumentation amplifier, followed by high pass filtering to remove offsets and low pass filtering to remove noise.  After that you'll have a higher gain op amp stage, usually about 20, maybe with some additional filtering.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an experienced electrical engineer, so don't take anything I say as necessarily true, but instead check everything. If any reader *is* an experienced electrical engineer, please check what I wrote. I'll be happy to accept corrections.

First of all, your amplifier circuit looks really weird. The inputs to the op amp are simply labeled "lead", but it's not clear if they are the same signal on two wires; a differential signal, where one is the negative of the other; or perhaps one is a signal and the other is cable (signal) ground. In any case, this circuit will not work, as several others have already pointed out:

- In a (non-differential) amplifier, there is only one input signal, not two. In your case, it looks like that ought to be the left lead. Connecting both leads (or one lead twice) to the inputs of an op amp is weird (outside of differential amplifiers).
- I'm going on about differential amplifiers because it seems to me that an ECG lead might well pick up common-mode noise, i.e., noise that affects both the signal lead and the signal ground equally and in the same direction, and differential amplifiers are very good at getting rid of such noise. But the picture you show is not a differential amplifier.
- The feedback voltage seems to be added to the right lead without a coupling capacitor. That means that if the feedback voltage contains a nontrivial DC component (as it seems it should in your case, see below), current could flow *into* your lead. If there aren't any protections in place in the ECG probe to prevent that from happening, the result could be unpleasant.

Then you say that your signal has a "potential" of 2 mV, but the picture on your oscilloscope shows a hefty DC bias of nearly 25 mV (if I'm reading this correctly) with a 2 mV signal riding on top of it. Do you want to amplify that bias as well, or just the raw AC signal?

What you also don't show is how you have connected the power. Have you connected the positive rail to the positive terminal of the battery (+9 V) and the negative to the negative terminal (0 V)? Or have you created a balanced supply of +/-4.5 V with a divider?

If you want to amplify the DC bias along with the signal in a non-differential amplifier, you can use the circuit depicted here. Don't worry if the op amp shown is not what you have. It's a bog-standard noninverting amplifier with gain of 101.

[image: Noninverting amplifier with gain of 101]

*However*, if I'm right about that +25 mV DC bias, that will be amplified as well. With a gain of 101, your output signal will have a bias of about +2.5 V, with a 0.2 V signal riding on top of that. If you want to remove that, put a small capacitor on the output. You can use an electrolytic cap, just make sure that the polarity is right.

I've put a bypass capacitor on the power connection in the circuit, which might or might not be needed, depending on what else that battery is powering.

Comment: You’ve accidentally drawn shorts across your (probably-unnecessary) decoupling caps. The + opamp input needs a path to a voltage reference or ground so that its bias current has a place to flow. The entire voltage swing at the input of the opamp needs to end up between the rails of the opamp so either have to bias up the input above ground, or add a negative supply for the opamp.

Comment: The leads originally drawn in are most likely two *different* leads.

Comment: Thanks @td127 for pointing out the shorts. I have also removed the superfluous cap to ground. The signal seems well biased above 0V (it's range seems about 24-28 mV), so a negative supply seems not to be needed.

Comment: @ScottSeidman: I thought so too, but then the circuit makes even less sense to me than it does when assuming that only one signal is to be amplified.

Answer (score 0):

The input common mode voltage range extends below ground, but the output voltage range does not.  This means that small output signals will not appear at the output, and large ones will be pseudo-half-wave rectified.

First, you don't show any power or decoupling connections.  Use two 9 V batteries, one for Vcc and one for Vee.  Connect your circuit grounds (GND) to the midpoint between the batteries.

Second, add a 1 M resistor from the non-inverting input to GND.  This establishes a DC operating point midway between the two power rails, centering the output signal.

The circuit still will be nowhere near a true differential amplifier usually used for this type of interface, but it might do something.

Answer (score 0):

To build  up an ECG machine with just an operational amplifier is utterly absurd. You need several instrument amplifiers and several electrodes in order to correctly deduce the signals from heart. In case you want to build one by yourself maybe you find some good ideas here: https://www.mikrocontroller.net/articles/EKG_mit_XMC_%C2%B5C

In case you wanted just to play with an opamp I think the closest schematic to your proposal is the non invertig opamp see below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbrmeJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Scott's response, the amplification of biopotentials requires converting ionic currents occurring at the skin interface to an electric current. This is typically done through Ag/AgCl (Silver/Silver Chloride) [electrodes](https://shop.neurospec.com/disposable-agagcl-pre-gelled-electrodes-el503) (those patches that the cardiologist puts on your chest when you get an EKG/ECG). In terms of the electronics conversion circuit, an instrumentation amplifier is the most 'affordable' and 'reliable' way to accomplish this. For instance, the [INA128/29](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina129.pdf?ts=1630931961630&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FINA129) or similar can be configured as the following image shows:

[image: INA128 Application example]

Additionally, care should be taken when powering such a circuit. A battery pack or an insulated power supply is mandatory when testing it in yourself or somebody.